# Dispaly popup when add record to Table

Tags: php, ajax, popup

I have a code that works like this: it takes the information live from the database and displays it in a table, every change made in the database is displayed instantly in the table, now I want that when every new record which is added to the database, after it is displayed in the table, a pop-up with sound will be displayed to notify that a new record has been added to the database.

fetch.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
// make is suitable for SSE
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
// make connection with database
include("db_connection.php");

// lets continue to check data in database with loop
$p = '';
while(true){
// now fetch data from database
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM data");
$r = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
        // get all data in json from
        $r[] = $row;
    }
}
$n = json_encode($r);
if(strcmp($p, $n) !== 0){
    // here data will shown on change
    echo "data:" . $n . "\n\n";
    $p = $n;
}
// here data is shown each time
// but we need data when change
// mean when data add, update or delete then show only

// this will show data even the loading is not completed
ob_end_flush();
flush();

// sleep process for 1 sec
sleep(1);
// but still data will not show
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Realtime Fetching From Normal Database</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            max-width: 900px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            margin: auto;
        }
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        table{
            width: 100%;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }
        table th,
        table td{
            padding: 15px 0px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
            text-align: left;
        }
        td:last-child{
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- create table to show data -->
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Realtime fetching From Normal Database</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- We will use SSE in JS to get event from server -->
    <!-- for best performance in realtime fetching -->
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("fetch.php");
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        var arrayData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var dataContainer = document.querySelector('tbody')
        dataContainer.innerHTML = ''
        arrayData.forEach(e => {
            dataContainer.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${e.id}</td>
                    <td>${e.name}</td>
                    <td>${e.message}</td>
                </tr>
            `;
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

db_connection.php

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
// create database first
$database = "yt_test"; 
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
if(!$con){
    echo 'Server not connected';
}
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, $database);
if(!$db){
    echo 'Database not connected';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pop-up a message together with playing a sound (e.g. mp3 file), you can use JS to trigger the popup by SweetAlert2 (autoclose in 2 seconds) and use HTML play() (e.g. audio.play()) of a mp3 file. (remember to place the mp3 file in the same directory of your scripts)

As an example, I will put the above into one function as `playsoundwithpopupautoclose()`

So, the code will be:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- SweetAlert2 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.2.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
var audio = new Audio('sound1.mp3');
</script>



<script>
function playsoundwithpopupautoclose() {
 audio.play();
 swal({
     title: "Record Added!",
     text: "A New Record has been added !",
     type: "",
     showConfirmButton: false, //hide OK button
    allowOutsideClick: false, 
     timer: 2000
     });

}
</script>
```

To trigger the above, you can place the playsoundwithpopupautoclose() function say at the end of source.onmessage block, so change

```
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("fetch.php");
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        var arrayData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var dataContainer = document.querySelector('tbody')
        dataContainer.innerHTML = ''
        arrayData.forEach(e => {
            dataContainer.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${e.id}</td>
                    <td>${e.name}</td>
                    <td>${e.message}</td>
                </tr>
            `;
        });
    }
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
    var source = new EventSource("fetch.php");
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        var arrayData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var dataContainer = document.querySelector('tbody')
        dataContainer.innerHTML = ''
        arrayData.forEach(e => {
            dataContainer.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${e.id}</td>
                    <td>${e.name}</td>
                    <td>${e.message}</td>
                </tr>
            `;
        });

playsoundwithpopupautoclose();

    }
</script>
```

Last but not least, please make sure that you have turned on the speaker on the client machine. Enjoy.